# Duplicate UI for mobile VR Cam

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a third party package that is for mobile VR. it consist of two cameras that giving me the feel of VR Look. I have designe a user interface which i want to show from my both VR cameras but the problem both camera showing single UI. My UI not duplicating for each camera instead its only showing single UI as image depicted. How can i duplicate My UI so that it show from both VR cams

[image]

Comment: Have you read the UI How Tos in the Unity Manual already? (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get my answer from [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/135659/draw-ui-from-two-vr-cameras/135686#135686), slightly outdated but valid post for unity 5.2 also:

1. Create two different canvases in your scene.
2. Select the Render Mode for each canvas as Screen Space - Camera.
3. Then assign the camera for each of those canvases as required.
4. Then that particular canvas will be drawn using the camera assigned
   to it.

It will render UI for both cams like in my mobile VR project.